# ValueError: bad input shape () in scikit learn

Tags: python, scipy, data-mining, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run following code, which uses cross validation to evaluate Linear Regression method in Scikit learn.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(train, outcomes == 't', test_size=0.4, random_state=0)
X_test.shape , y_test.shape
model = LogisticRegression(C=0.1)
model.fit(X_train[:X_train.shape[0]/2], y_train[:y_train.size/2] == 't')
preds1 = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
model.fit(X_train[(X_train.shape[0]/2 + 1):], y_train[(y_train.size/2) +1 :] == 't')
preds2 = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
preds = (preds1+preds2)/2
```

At "model.fit(X_train[:(X_train.shape[0]/2], y_train[:y_train.size/2] == 't')". 
I'm getting error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ROC.py", line 137, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train[:X_train.shape[0]/2], y_train[:y_train.size/2] == 't')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 674, in fit
    y_ind = self._enc.fit_transform(y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 124, in fit_transform
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 310, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape ()
```

What is the reason for this? How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the shape of the X and y that you pass?

Comment: As Andy says, you are passing a variable called `train` in the first line and you are not showing us what it is.